sudo netplan apply causes wait for network to be configured to fail
My issue does not start at the boot process, but once I type sudo netplan apply. I've done the same thing on other computers and some work and some don't.
I configured netplan like this:

and when I do sudo netplan apply, this is what I sometimes get:

Normally the computer should get a 172.16.0.x address, and I check that with ip a, but in this case, it just sticks to the DHCP. When I check systemctl status systemd-networkd-wait-online.service this is what I get.


Does this question/answer help?

@mpboden That didn't help unfortunately. It might have stopped the warning but the ip still stays 192.168.99.X when normally it would go 172.16.0.x

Please update you question with the output of ls /etc/systemd/network and ls /run/systemd/network. If there are any files in these locations related to the usb0 interface, show us the contents of those files.
